# flip coordinates when drawing to control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls

I am drawing a graph on a control, but 0,0 is at the top-left hand corner of the control. Is there a way to flip the coordinates so that 0,0 is at the lower left corner of the control?

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF? You might like to update the tags on your question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are using WinForms, then you might find that you can flip the Y-Axis using [Graphics.ScaleTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhc2xxtx.aspx):

```
private void ScaleTransformFloat(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Begin graphics container
    GraphicsContainer containerState = e.Graphics.BeginContainer();

    // Flip the Y-Axis
    e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(1.0F, -1.0F);

    // Translate the drawing area accordingly
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0.0F, -(float)Height);

    // Whatever you draw now (using this graphics context) will appear as
    // though (0,0) were at the bottom left corner
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue, 3), 50, 0, 100, 40);

    // End graphics container
    e.Graphics.EndContainer(containerState);

    // Other drawing actions here...
}
```

You only need to include the begin/end container calls if you want to do additional drawing using the regular coordinate system as well.  More information on graphics containers is [available on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.endcontainer.aspx).

As mentioned by Tom in the comments, this approach requires the `Height` value to be available with a correct value. If you try this and see nothing being drawn, ensure that value is correct in a debugger.

Comment: Thanks Eric.  I've updated my answer and included information on using graphics containers to isolate these transformations from other changes.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I'm not a WinForms wiz yet. As it turns out "Height" doesn't relate to the current control. I called this in my panel.OnPaint and nothing got painted. Mentioning that you assume youre drawing onto the form itself could save others some time, as it could have saved me some debugging time ;)

Comment: @Tom, I've added a clarification based upon your experience. Thanks.

Comment: @DrewNoakes, this solution is not complete, cause text produced by DrawString is invalid, e.g is flipped vertically.

Comment: Quite right. This won't work if you're drawing text.

Comment: oh but it *does* work with text. it's flipped vertically, it's supposed to be. the transformation affects everything, why would text be excluded? you could apply a secondary transform to the area the text will be drawn to (wrap the drawstring function and use measurestring to determine the size of the affected rectangular portion).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple UserControl that demonstrates how to do this:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(1.0F, -1.0F);
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0.0F, -(float)Height);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(0, 0), new Point(Width, Height));

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but using the `Size` (or `Height`) properties of the control, it is easy to calculate flipped coordinates: Just draw to `Height-y`.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of but if you use (x,Control.Height-y) you get the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

in short no, however if i am drawing on controls a lot i have a few functions that help me:

```
Point GraphFromRaster(Point point)  {...}
Point RasterFromGraph(Point point)  {...}
```

this way i keep all the conversion in one place, no worrying about things like `y - this.Height` scattered about the code.