# GDI+ RotateFlip is not rotating on WMF Image?

Tags: c++, mfc, rotation, gdi+

In C++ when using GDI+ RotateFlip function for rotating WMF image the image is not getting rotated.
I used below code for rotating.

```
Graphics graphics(hdc);
Image image(L"Crayons.WMF");
image.RotateFlip(Rotate90FlipX);
graphics.DrawImage(&image, 10, 10, image.GetWidth(), image.GetHeight());
```

RotateFlip function rotates bmp and jpg images properly.

Will RotateFlip function support WMF image?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Metafiles are a list of drawing commands, not a raster representation so the rotate flip doesn't work.

Draw the metafile to a bitmap and then rotate that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrew.How to draw metafile in bitmap and rotate it?Could you please suggest some links?

Answer (score 1):

Use Graphics.RotateTransform and Graphics.ScaleTransform instead. Look here for inspiration:  [flip coordinates when drawing to control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485745/flip-coordinates-when-drawing-to-control)