# Flip coordinates when drawing set of rectangles

Tags: c#, winforms, shapes

I am trying to draw set of squares but the origin(0,0) of squares was in top left corner initially and I wanted squares to render from bottom right corner, 
and I found this code to flip the co ordinates, but nothing is rendering on  winform.

I know that I have gone wrong in Height attribute of TranslateTransform. I dont get as to why Height is required as i am trying to draw a set of 2d squares.

I tried hardcoding the height attribute still of no use.

```
public void ScaleTransformFloat(PaintEventArgs e,List<Square> lstSquare)
    {
        int Height = 10;
        // Begin graphics container
        GraphicsContainer containerState = e.Graphics.BeginContainer();

        // Flip the Y-Axis
        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(1.0F, -1.0F);

        // Translate the drawing area accordingly
        //
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0.0F, -(float)Height);

        // Whatever you draw now (using this graphics context) will appear        as
        // though (0,0) were at the bottom left corner

    //User-defined function to draw a square    
        DrawSquare(e,lstSquare);
        // End graphics container
        e.Graphics.EndContainer(containerState);


    }
```

Method to draw set of squares

```
  public void DrawSquare(PaintEventArgs e,List<Square> lstSquare)
    {
      foreach(Square s in lstSquare){
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0,0 ,s.m_Side, s.m_Side);
      }
    }
```

Comment: a) not sure why get things so complicated (and possibly just as wrong) with transforming a Graphics object when you could just as well just adapt the drawing code.. b) the DrawSquare draws everything at (0,0), no matter what you did before, all squares sit on top of each other.. c) 10 pixels for the total height, really?

Comment: Actually this is my first assignment in drawing shapes.Initially all squares were getting rendered from top left and i wanted them to render from bottom left.I came across [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485745/flip-coordinates-when-drawing-to-control)) which would help me render squares from left bottom.But nothing is showing up. I wanted to know why height is required as i am drawing a set of 2d sqaure

Comment: The Height is not a 3d height. It is the total Height of the target control you want to draw on.

Imaging flipping a sheet of paper topwise by the top left corner. Now you need to move it down. But by what distance? Answer: The paper size..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing matrix operation like transformations usually the **order** does matter.

In your case you need to either **translate first, then scale/flip** or reverse the direction of the translation. Your code seems to get it right.

The `Height` is not a 3d height. It is the total `Height` of the target control  you want to draw on.

Imagine laying a sheet of paper on your control; the control is your viewport. Now imagine flipping the paper topwise by the top left edge. It has left the viewport. Now you need to move it down. But by what distance? Answer: The paper's height..

Your code has a `Height = 10` pixels. This is certainly not the size of your control, right? Maybe it comes from code you copied; there it probably meant the `Form's Height`. If you want to draw on the Form also (usually not a good idea), simply delete the line `int Height = 10;`!

Let's do a simple example: We draw a few rectangles onto a `Panel`:

[image]

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(1, -1);
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0, -panel1.Height);
    }
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Violet, 1, 1, 33, 33);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.OrangeRed, 11, 11, 133, 55);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Magenta, 44, 11, 233, 77);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Olive, 55, 44, 33, 99);
}

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Invalidate();
}
```

After checking the `CheckBox` the result is flipped:

[image]

Also note that your `DrawSquare` draws all squares at the same location `(0,0)`. Not sure if that is what you want..

Final note: `DrawRectangle` has a nasty habit of overdrawing the botton and right sides by one pixel. After changing the first loaction from `(1,1)` to `(0,0)` the (then) bottom side will be cut off. You might consider translating the graphics coodinates by 1 pixel less..

Comment: As you said the rectangles with sides on the x axis (both bottom and top side of panel) dont get rendered,ie only 3 sides of rectangle are getting drawn where one of the sides is on x-axis....and all four sides of a  rectangle getting rendered when no side is on x axis. how do i solve this?

Comment: No way around it. Either make them 1 pixel smaller or draw them one pixel further off the edges. Using a Height +- 1 is a cheap and transparent way to achieve this..