# Graphics flip the canvas vertically

Tags: c#, graphics, panel, coordinate-systems

I'm putting coordinates from a List called `line`, scaling them with my panel1 and drawing the lines that connect them using `GraphicsPath`. The problem I'm getting is that the image is flipped vertically, probably due to to the panel1's `(0,0)` cordinates being in the top left as opposed as my normal coordinates originating from the coordinate system that has the zeroes in the bottom left. The code is as follows:

```
 Graphics G = e.Graphics;
 GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
 foreach (var line in tockeKoordinate)
 {
     gp.AddLine((float)(line.startX), (float)(line.startY),
                (float)(line.endX),   (float)(line.endY));
     gp.CloseFigure();
 }
 var rect = gp.GetBounds();
 var scale = Math.Min(1f * (int)(panel1.ClientSize.Width)  / rect.Width,
                      1f * (int)(panel1.ClientSize.Height) / rect.Height);

 using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.DarkGreen, 0.0001f))
 {
     G.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
     G.Clear(Color.White);
     G.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
     G.TranslateTransform(-rect.X, -rect.Y);
     G.DrawPath(pen, gp);
 }
```

I've been searching and it somehow has got to do to the G.TranslateTransform line, but I've had zero success adding minus prefixes to the values...

Comment: You really should just use the normal graphics convention of (0, 0) being in top-left rather than doing it from the mathematical convention and then flipping later.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497929/flip-coordinates-when-drawing-set-of-rectangles/37498798?s=1|0.5230#37498798) how to use a flipped graphics object. Note that you need to know the size of your canvas!

Comment: @Jashaszun the source GPS coordinates are like that, and lots of them so can't change them manually unfortunately.

Comment: You can change them before adding them to the GraphicsPath though.

Comment: @TaW solved eventually, the order does matter like you said in the linked solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, with the help of TaW and James Lambert. Needed to flip the axis by negating the Y parameters of the `ScaleTransform`, but also bring the canvas down using `TranslateTransform`:

```
  G.TranslateTransform(0, +panel1.ClientSize.Height);
  G.ScaleTransform(scale, -scale);
```

Answer (score 2):

TranslateTransform just moves things around but cannot flip anything. You can flip it by negating one of the parameters to ScaleTransform.

Comment: Tried that, the screen just goes blank.