# How to change the origin in Windows Forms Bitmap?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Bitmap object in C# Windows Forms. The origin (where axis start) in this Bitmap object is located in the top-left corner. How can I change the origin to the bottom-left corner, like in usual graphs? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think that's possible.  You could define your own class that uses whatever origin you want, copy data from the `Bitmap` to your custom object, and work with that.  But then you lose a lot of the functionality that a `Bitmap` provides.

Comment: first of which, what have you tried to do yourself?

Comment: This is just how windows forms work... It's not that hard to just use that way to be completely honest. You'll be much better off in the long run getting used to it this way, since that's how all of the controls work.

Comment: There may be a way using GDI+ Transforms but we'd need to know a bit more about what your code looks like. Are you placing the Bitmap into an Image control of some kind ? If so, what control is the bitmap hosted in ?

Comment: @PhillipH I take Bitmap from PictureBox.

Answer (score 1):

You can flip the Y coordinates in a picture box by using the code in the following answer;

[flip coordinates when drawing to control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485745/flip-coordinates-when-drawing-to-control)

```
private void ScaleTransformFloat(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Begin graphics container
    GraphicsContainer containerState = e.Graphics.BeginContainer();

    // Flip the Y-Axis
    e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(1.0F, -1.0F);

    // Translate the drawing area accordingly
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0.0F, -(float)Height);

    // Whatever you draw now (using this graphics context) will appear as
    // though (0,0) were at the bottom left corner
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue, 3), 50, 0, 100, 40);

    // End graphics container
    e.Graphics.EndContainer(containerState);

    // Other drawing actions here...
}
```