# Draw theme background part for right-to-left interface in WinForms Graphics

Tags: winforms, winapi, graphics, gdi+, right-to-left

We have a legacy code that draws header parts using the current Windows visual style. The drawing is performed on a GDI+ Graphics object but using the WinAPI DrawThemeBackground function. The core part of this code looks like this:

```cs
[DllImport("uxtheme.dll", EntryPoint = "DrawThemeBackground")]
public static extern int DrawThemeBackground(IntPtr hTheme, IntPtr hdc, int iPartId, int iStateId, ref iGRECT pRect, ref iGRECT pClipRect);

IntPtr myHdc = graphics.GetHdc();
DrawThemeBackground(
    GetThemeData(themeClass),
    myHdc,
    themePart,
    themeState,
    ref myRect, ref myRect);
```

Now we need to mirror the drawing part for the right-to-left interface. How to do that for the WinForms Graphics object if we draw with WinAPI functions? Is there a GDI+ or GDI instruction or setting that can flip the output from DrawThemeBackground on-the-fly?

---

P.S. I do know that I can prepare a temporary bitmap with the mirrored output:

```cs
using (Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, graphics))
{
    using (Graphics myGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap))
    {
        DrawTheme(myGraphics, ThemeClasses.header, myPart, myState, 0, 0, width, height);
    }
    myBitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
    graphics.DrawImage(myBitmap, x, y);
}
```

My intention is to use a GDI+ transformation or something similar that can flip all drawing to the Graphics on-the-fly.

Comment: I've never attempted this myself, but would [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485745/flip-coordinates-when-drawing-to-control#1486019) help?

Comment: @DonBoitnott, No, Graphics.ScaleTransform and TranslateTransform does not affect WinAPI drawing. At least, I could not make it work.

Comment: Take a look at GDI's SettLayout function, it can take a flag to specify right-to-left layout. I don't know whether UX works with that setting or not but is the first thing I would check.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, WinAPI SetLayout was the first thing I tried. Unfortunately, it flips the whole coordinate system (X-axis), but I need to do that only for particular rectangles I am drawing theme parts in.